# Node.js Ajax Call Modify JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, node.js

This is my first time using node.js I have managed to successfully send json data to my node.js server but I can't figure out how to pass the json data into a function inside the server and modify it. My applications intention is a simple timer to showcase how node.js works. If someone could give me some assistance with this it would be greatly appreciated.

Update, I was able to get my code to work in the console the timer is now counting but it is not writing back to the html page.

Below is my code,

```css
function incrementTimer(time) {
    
    if (time.second != 60) {
        time.second +=1;
    } else {
        time.second = 0;
        if (time.minute != 60) {
            time.minute +=1;
        } else {
            time.minute = 0;
            time.hour +=1;
        }
    }
    return time;
}

var port = 8080;
var http = require("http");
var server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', request);
server.listen(port);
function request(request, response) {
    console.log('Request Recieved');
    var store = "";

    request.on('data', function(data) 
    {
        store += data;
    });
    store = incrementTimer(store);
    request.on('end', function() 
    {  console.log(store);
        var storeObj = JSON.parse(store);
        incrementTimer(storeObj);
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/json");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.end(JSON.stringify(storeObj)
    });
 }  
console.log('Server Started');
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Node.js Demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Demo of Node.JS</h1>
        <div id="timer"></div>
        <button onclick="startTimer(0,0,0)">Start Timer</button>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function startTimer(s,m,h) {               
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://localhost:8080",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    dataType: "json",
                    data:JSON.stringify({second: s, minute: m, hour: h}),
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#timer').text(data.hour + ":" + data.minute + ":" + data.second);
                        setTimeout(function(){ startTimer(data.second,data.minute,data.hour); }, 1000);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(xhr.status);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it possible this is caused by the recursion taking place in the success message, does the DOM not get written too until after it exits the success message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple mistake I was trying to write to an id but it was a class.